# Multiple Sites with Different IP Addresses

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm not an admin so this may seem to be a very simplistic question. Currently, I have ten ASP.NET Web Forms sites on a W2K8 hosted VM - I manage it myself. Right now, all the sites have the same server IP address and I want to change this so that each site has its own IP (that with which they were originally registered). Initially, I used the server IP when setting the bindings - I'm guessing that IIS set these as host headers?

What are the steps involved in setting this up in IIS? Do I have to change the way email is configured in all the individual Web.Config files? (currently mailing from server IP mail host).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally what you need to do is:

1. Assign the extra IPs to the network adapter properties in the Control Panel.
2. Edit the bindings in IIS like in the image below (the IP Address dropdown) [image]
3. Change your A records to reflect the new IP address for each website on your DNS server.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by #3... I thought I could get the registered IPs for each site and assign them as in steps #1 and #2. Are you saying I have to log into the clients' registrar accounts and update something there?

Comment: No you don't need to change anything at the domain's registrar, rathen on the nameservers their configured to point at.

Comment: For example if domain.com has the nameservers ns1.uberwebhost.com and ns2.uberwebhost.com then you need to go into the DNS zone of those two nameservers and change the A record that points domain.com from the current IP (let say 12.34.56.11) to the new IP you will assign it to (eg. 12.34.56.12)

Comment: All these sites are currently live, so the nameservers must be already configured, yes?

Comment: Yes, they're definitely configured since they're live. BUT: They're configured to point to IP A, now if you go and assign them a new IP under IIS ie IP B, you also need to change that on the nameserver, so that he directs the queries to the new IP.

Comment: Keep in mind that changing a domains IP address can take between 24-48 hours to propagate around the internet (depending on the TTL value). This is called TTL caching or propagation and here's a link that explains how you can speed it up [link](http://www.technologytricks.com/speed-up-dns-propagation/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign each IP to the NIC in the Control Panel. After that, you edit the bindings in IIS like you mentioned. That should be all that you need to know. You shouldn't have to change your web.configs.